# move drupal from one folder to another

Tags: drupal

Okay. I screwed things up a little. I have shared hosting. I tried to installed drupal into website.com/ root directory. it said: .htaccess already exists. So I didn't bother, thinking I could fix this later, I installed it under the directory, and started developing.
like this: website.com/folder/
now I do not know how to put my website in the root. Any easy way to do that? or at least point root to my folder?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go into `sites/default/settings.php` and change the `$base_url` to match the root of your new site. Drupal will then use that as the URL to base it's paths on.

The only things that might not work properly are links that are part of content, you'll need to update these manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it shouldn't be hard to fix that. Drupal keeps most reference relative to the directory root so moving it up a level won't really confuse it—especially if it's a new site and you don't need to worry about inbound links.

Have you tried just moving everything up a level? Make a backup of the existing .htaccess file incase there's some reason you need it later and then replace it with Drupal's.